# Webmail client that can open multiple email addresses at once like a desktop client

Tags: email-client, webmail

I've got 5 email domains with multiple email addresses on each domain. Traditional webmail clients only seem to allow you to browse a single account at a time (ie, you log into that account). With over 20 email addresses I need to monitor, this is obviously a major time sink.

Is there a (preferably OSS, unix-based) webmail client that simulates a desktop email client, ie I log in once and can access all the email addresses from a central control panel? I've considered using a ticket system but that is overkill and not really used to my needs.

Answer (score 3):

AfterLogic WebMail Pro has this functionality (there will be a dropdown where you can select an account from your account list).

Available for ASP.NET and PHP. http://www.afterlogic.com/webmail-client

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [PolarisMail E-mail Hosting](http://www.polarismail.com/Enhanced-E-mail-hosting-service/)

Their Webmail client allows for the management of multiple IMAP accounts while maintaining a unified calendar/address book

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Gmail's POP3 feature ?

Check this out: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=21288

Comment: Hmmm, that would be handy but unfortunately it only handles up to five other email accounts, I've got over 20 to manage and it's set to increase over time.

Comment: Don't you have a auto-forward feature ?

Comment: I've looked at that but it is not suited to my needs. The tl;dr version is that I've thought about the situation and decided to look for a system as outlined in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Zoho Mail. It's got the power of Gmail but a more traditional interface. I'm not aware of any limit on the number of accounts it can handle.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything to either confirm or deny that it supports multiple accounts, but this popped up on Google Reader earlier and might be worth a look, it describes using the MUTT command line email tool:

[Mutt described at Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5043622/mutt-delivers-email-from-the-command-line)